# Roslyn compiler causes recycling of application pool during compilation

Tags: asp.net, iis, compilation, roslyn

I have a fairly large ASP.NET website with [Roslyn compiler installed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/1.0.8). I have also app pool recycling enabled for 'private memory usage' (IIS 10, limit set to 4GB). I was wondering why my website recycles with event log message ID 5117

> A worker process serving application pool 'pool_name' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.

even though the committed memory of application pool itself is well under 1GB. By test&trial I came to conclusion it's caused by the Roslyn compiler, which is most probably ran under the pool and its memory is also counted towards the recycle limit.

So the question is - is this behavior normal and how can it be set up in a way the compilation does not cause the recycling? (other than precompilation)

Comment: "By test&trial"? Why cannot you collect ASP.NET tracing to really identify the culprit? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing/ Any guess should be avoided right now.